# JSX is being rendered as Text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have an API endpoint which returns JSX as data, if I try to render it, the output being rendered is the whole JSX as text, instead of following the tags. How can I fix this?

```
export function Card({ product }) {
  return data.data.electricity[0].why_us
}
```

The data attribute after getting it

```
"why_us": "<ul>\r\n\t<li>Join over 1 million Australians!<\/li>\r\n\t<li>Freedom to choose the way you pay with flexible billing options.<\/li>\r\n\t<li>Benefit from no late payment fees, no fees for paper bills, and no credit card fees (including American Express).<\/li>\r\n\t<li>Access your account online 24\/7 with My Account.<\/li>\r\n\t<li>No lock-in contracts, exit fees or paper bill fees.<\/li>\r\n\t<li>Gain access to savings and special offers through&nbsp;<a href=\"https:\/\/www.alintaenergy.com.au\/nsw\/residential\/customer-rewards\/rewards-shop\/\" target=\"_blank\">Alinta Energy Rewards<\/a><\/li>\r\n\t<li>Save up to 48% on movie tickets with Alinta Energy rewards.<\/li>\r\n\t<li>Multi-award winning taking out one of the top spots in the 2019 Mozo People&rsquo;s Choice Awards in the Highly Trusted, Most Recommended and Excellent Customer Service categories.<\/li>\r\n\t<li>Proud Platinum Partner of Cricket Australia and Principal Partner of the Australian Men&rsquo;s Cricket Team.<\/li>\r\n\t<li>2019 Winner - Canstar Blue&rsquo;s Most Satisfied Business Customers award.<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>",
```

They output I get after rendering is as shown

[image]

How can I solve this error? My way of thinking is that the `why_us` property returns string, hence JSX returns string to render, if that's the case, how do I convert the string to JSX?

Comment: It's a string, not jsx. Remove `"` if you want jsx

Comment: Try `return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.data.electricity[0].why_us }} /> );`, just make sure you actually trust what's going to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you code in ReactJS.

If it is, you can use the attribute `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. It converts text in HTML. Be very careful with this attribute. ReactJS named it `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for a reason. You can easily create xss fail with this attribute.

I advise you to read this article before use it : https://blog.logrocket.com/using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-a-react-application/

```
export function Card({ product }) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data.data.electricity[0].why_u}} />
}
```

Comment: You just extended my comment into an answer ;-)